# already created wordpress site is not accessible with wamp

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I have found a wordpress site with database. Then,

1. Imported databse into mysql
2. update wp-config.php according to my database credentials
3. Copied the wordpress project in www
4. Try to access the folder

But still unable to access the site

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. 
>   Search Google
>   for localhost 4001 TLL 
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Then (I googled and found need to check option table) i go to wp_option table here i found site url `http://127.0.0.1:4001/TLL/` and home `http://127.0.0.1:4001/TLL/`

then, i also try this url but showing  me

> This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

which thing i am missing.?

Comment: under www ,you might have given some folder name to your project ,does TLL represents the same folder.

Comment: Yeah, TLL the same folder

Answer (score 0):

What port is your wamp server serving on?

Change the port 4001 to the wamp server html port in the options table and also check the config.php for any reference to port 4001 and change that as needed.

Also is your wordpress installation in a directory call TTL on the WAMP server?

Comment: I have changed the site url `http://127.0.0.1:80/TLL/` but still the same problem. And there is no port mentino in config php

Comment: In wp-config.php do you have any lines starting with define('WPSITEURL.... or define('WPHOME.....

Comment: No, there is nothing like that in wp-config.php